# Flutter - How to create a vertical line between two widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to create a vertical line between two widgets like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiFtf.jpg

I could do it but for a fixed size. If this size changes, layout got messy like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ov4A.jpg

Here's my code:

```dart
Widget listItem(TripsData item) {
    var startDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yy - HH:mm').format(DateTime.parse(item.start));
    var endDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yy - HH:mm').format(DateTime.parse(item.end));
    return Card(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          drawDestinationLine(Colors.red),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: drawDestinationCircle('A', Colors.blue),
                title: Text(startDate),
                subtitle: Text(item.locationStart),
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0)),
              ListTile(
                leading: drawDestinationCircle('B', Colors.blue),
                title: Text(endDate),
                subtitle: Text(item.locationEnd),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Does someone have a solution to help me with this?

Let me know if need more code, but StackOverflow didn't let me put more code here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the package *timelines 0.1.0* which makes this easily possible

Check on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines) and the corresponding [Github repo](https://github.com/chulwoo-park/timelines) for nice examples.

One of the sample use-cases looks like what you are looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use the Stack, Positioned, and ConstrainedBox widgets to create the desired arrangement.

Something like this pseudocode, you will need to supply correct coordinates:

```
Stack ( children: [
   Positioned ( left: 0.0 , top : 0.0 , child:  
     ListTile (leading: drawDestinationCircle('A', Colors.blue),
                title: Text(startDate),
                subtitle: Text(item.locationStart),
              )),
   Positioned ( left: 0.0 , bottom : 0.0 , child:  
     ListTile (leading: drawDestinationCircle('B', Colors.blue),
                  title: Text(endDate),
                  subtitle: Text(item.locationEnd),
                )),
   Positioned ( left 20.0 , top : 20.0 
              , child: ConstrainedBox(
                       constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                              minHeight: 5.0,
                              minWidth: 5.0,
                              maxHeight: 30.0,
                              maxWidth: 5.0,
                              ),
                           child: new DecoratedBox(
                             decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                           )
                       ),
              )
          ]);
```

Comment: I tried this, the circles were in place, but not the texts, the texts just vanished

Comment: As noted, the above is pseudocode.  The new Widgets noted are the ones which will accomplish what you desire to do.  You might want to move away from ListTile and perhaps use Row & Text and & Image/Icon Widgets to accomplish the look you desire.

I generally have good luck with ListTile though.  Perhaps you may want to explore further Text widget options.  Or perhaps temporarily shorten you text to perhaps one character to see if it is a bleed situation of some type.